# Stop argparse from globbing filepath

Tags: python, argparse

I am using python argparse with the following argument definition:

```
parser.add_argument('path', nargs=1, help='File path to process')
```

But when I enter my command with a *wildcard* argument, `argparse` globs all the file paths and terminates with an error.

How do I get `argparse` not to glob the files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's not `argparse` but the shell that's globbing the wildcards before it even starts your Python interpreter.

Comment: you can change the line to `nargs='+'` and let the shell do the globbing.  `+` is interpreted as 'at least one argument' and you will get a list of strings in `args.path`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I get argparse not to glob the files?

You don't.

You get the shell to stop globbing.

However.  Let's think for a moment.

You're  saying this in your code

```
parser.add_argument('path', nargs=1, help='File path to process')
```

But you are actually providing wild-cards when you run it.

One of those two is wrong.  Either stop providing wild-cards at run time or fix argparse to allow multiple filenames.

Answer (score 12):

The shell is expanding the wildcard argument before `argparse` gets a chance to see it. Put quotes around the wildcard argument to prevent the shell from expanding it.

You could later perform the wildcard expansion with [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#module-glob).

Answer (score 4):

The globbing is done by your shell, not by the argparse module. print `sys.argv` at the beginning and you will see what argparse gets as input.